# Catenary module

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

We call an $R$-module $M$ catenary with $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is Noetherian local ring if for each pair of prime submodules $K$ and $L$ of $M$ with $K\subset L$ all saturated chains of prime submodules of $M$ from $K$ to $L$ have a common finite length. Prove that it is equal to this condition: Let $Q\in Min_{R}{M}$. The maximal chain of prime ideals between $Q$ and $m$ has the same length $n=dim_{R}{M}$.

All of things I know:

+$Ann_{R}(K)=Ass_{R}(K)=P$ with $P\in Spec(R)$

+Because $K\subset L$ and the definition of prime module, $Ass_{R}(L)=Ann_{R}(L)=Ass_{R}(K)=Ann_{R}(K)$

Comment: A copy of this question was also posted on MO: [catenary module](http://mathoverflow.net/q/266654)

Comment: Perhaps you might have a look at some basic information [about cross-posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info). Personally, I consider the advice given in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) very reasonable.

Comment: I think I will not recieve the answer at there, so I try posting it in MO. If it is not allowed, I will delete this post at there.

Comment: I would advise against deleting the post on MO - at least until you get feedback from MO users whether it is suitable for that site. (If not for other reason, then because too many deleted questions can be a reason for [question ban](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info).) But if you plan posting some stuff on both sites, the answer I linked is probably worth reading. To me the most important suggestion given there seems to be that you should always include a link to the question on the other site.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you so much.